# Searching and Handling git objects

Tags: git, git-bash

I'm trying to filter through the historical content of a file in my git repository. There is a line in some of the files that contains the string 'BEAM:A_BOOK', and in the 7th comma separated value of this line is a value I want to retrieve for further processing. I think, ideally, I'd end up with something like a dictionary with the SHA-1 hash of the commit, and this A_BOOK value for the past versions of this file.

Example of first few lines of a File. Note the value I'd hope to retrieve from this version of the file would be '56.0':

> `# Date: 2018-12-21 01:49:16.888`
> `PV,SELECTED,TIMESTAMP,STATUS,SEVERITY,VALUE_TYPE,VALUE,READBACK,READBACK_VALUE,DELTA,READ_ONLY`
>
> `REA_EXP:LINE,0,1544047322.881066957,NO_ALARM,NONE,enum,"JENSA~[UDF;AT-TPC;GPL;JENSA]",,"---",,true`
>
> `REA_BTS19:BEAM:OPTICSFILE,0,1541798820.065952460,NO_ALARM,NONE,string,"BTS19_test3.data",,"---",,true`
>
> `REA_BTS19:BEAM:A_BOOK,0,1545322510.562031883,NO_ALARM,NONE,double,"56.0",,"---",,true`

Ultimately, I'll extend this to retrieve a couple values and do some math to perform more complicated filtering. More background: we store the Atomic Mass and Charge values for ion beams we deliver for nuclear physics experiments in text files under version control. These text files act as our 'save sets', and are filled with more than this mass and charge info, as they also include machine values we would restore if we wanted to run that beam again. My goal is to filter these files by the Charge:Mass ratio of the beams we ran with them.

So far, this seems to get me most of my information:

> `git grep 'BTS19:BEAM:A_BOOK' $(git rev-list --all) | grep RFQ-JENSA_Setpoint.snp`

Which spits outsomething like this:

> `16eca44985214b790eb6ca8241ad86728b4fd3ae:RFQ-JENSA_Setpoints.snp:REA_BTS19:BEAM:A_BOOK,0,1531323944.085330133,NO_ALARM,NONE,double,"2.0",,"---",,true`
>
> `6e585c905444f25e18edfe1eeb32ced2de72ed7c:RFQ-JENSA_Setpoints.snp:REA_BTS19:BEAM:A_BOOK,0,1531323944.085330133,NO_ALARM,NONE,double,"2.0",,"---",,true`
>
> `bc202d5f21f9829fa3701ca636657ee1b0a73e25:RFQ-JENSA_Setpoints.snp:REA_BTS19:BEAM:A_BOOK,0,1531323944.085330133,NO_ALARM,NONE,double,"2.0",,"---",,true`
>
> `etc...`

However, I'd like to see something like:

> `<hash>:<Retrieved A_BOOK Value>`

Or, based on the output I just showed, I'd hope to see something like this:

> `16eca44985214b790eb6ca8241ad86728b4fd3ae:2.0`
>
> `6e585c905444f25e18edfe1eeb32ced2de72ed7c:2.0`
>
> `bc202d5f21f9829fa3701ca636657ee1b0a73e25:2.0`
>
> `etc...`

And eventually include some math to show something more meaningful:

> `<hash>:<Retrieved Q_BOOK Value>/<Retrieved A_BOOK Value>`

Is there a better way to go about this?
What's a good way to retrieve this information?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you're interested in a particular file within each revision, consider adding `-- <pathspec>` to the `git grep` invocation.  That is, instead of:

> ```
> git grep 'BTS19:BEAM:A_BOOK' $(git rev-list --all) | grep RFQ-JENSA_Setpoint.snp
> ```

you could start with:

```
git grep 'BTS19:BEAM:A_BOOK' $(git rev-list --all) -- RFQ-JENSA_Setpoint.snp
```

You will still get the lines, but faster, since `git grep` can skip all the files that *don't* have `RFQ-JENSA_Setpoint.snp` in their names.  (Note that a `<pathspec>` is not the same as a regular expression: if you really wanted to allow any character, e.g., `RFQ-JENSA_SetpointXsnp` and `RFQ-JENSA_SetpointYsnp` as file names, you'd have to use `-- 'RFQ-JENSA_Setpoint?snp'` here.  I'm guessing your second grep was overly permissive.  REs are more expressive in general than path globs, but for this particular case, even if you really did mean "any character", glob has `?` to allow that.)

Complicating matters, you may find that in a large repository, `$(git rev-list --all)` produces enough strings to overflow argv limits.  (What the argv limits are on your system is not something I can guess.)  In that case, you may need to pipe `git rev-list --all` through `xargs`:

```
git rev-list --all | xargs -I % git grep 'BTS19:BEAM:A_BOOK' % -- RFQ-JENSA_Setpoint.snp
```

Annoyingly, this spawns one separate `git grep` for each revision, which will slow you right back down.  (If you have a BSD-style `xargs` you can use `-J` instead of `-I`; or consider the GNU [parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) command.)

To break these up and extract the 7th comma-separated value, consider replacing the `:` with `,` and using `awk`:

```
... | sed 's/:/,/' | awk -F, '{print $1 ":" $8}'
```

although if you need proper CSV quote handling, a separate tool is probably more appropriate.  (Given your example this would print `<hash>:"2.0"`, too, with the quotes.)

Comment: Thank you for your response!!

Comment: I'll try your suggestions asap, and respond again.

Comment: THIS IS SO COOL!
However, I could not get xargs to work right.
This is what I used:

    `git grep 'BTS19:BEAM:A_BOOK' $(git rev-list --all) -- RFQ-JENSA_Setpoint.snp | sed 's/:/,/' | awk -F, '{print $1 ":" $8}'`

Comment: I admit I haven't tested the xargs variant with `git grep` but it seems like it should work. However, if you're not running out of argument space when using `$(git rev-list --all)` there's no need for xargs and it will just slow everything down, so you could wait until you find you need it.